# Создать копию массива объектов с изменением названия поля

Tags: javascript, typescript

Получаю с сервера массив объектов `tempArray`. Подскажите, как создать копию этого массива и переименовать поле `name` на `title`

```
let tempArray = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 11
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Jerry',
    age: 13
  }
  ...
]

let newArr = tempArray.forEach(item => { ?
})
```

Comment: `forEach` - ничего не возвращает

Comment: @Podushkoved указывайте, пожалуйста, осмысленную причину правки.

Answer (score 0):

Не `forEach`, а `map`

```js
const tempArray = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 11
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Jerry',
    age: 13
  }
]


const newArr = tempArray.map(item => ({
  // Так ссылка не скопируется и оригинальный массив останется чист
  id: item.id,
  title: item.name,
  age: item.age,
}));

console.log(newArr);
```

**Ссылки** 
[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, для создания копии массива нужно использовать не метод `forEach`, который просто перебирает элементы массива, а метод `map` который модифицирует элементы и создает новый массив из модифицированных элементов.

Копирование объекта происходит так

```
res = Object.assign({title: item.name}, item);
```

здесь в объект `{title: item.name}` добавляются все поля из `item`.

Ну а потом, в новом объекте нужно просто удалить ненужное поле

```
delete res.name;
```

```js
let tempArray = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 11
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Jerry',
    age: 13
  }
]


let newArr = tempArray.map(item => {
  res = Object.assign({title: item.name}, item);
  delete res.name;
  return res;
})

console.log(newArr);
```